# Exception occurred during file download in Firebase

Tags: firebase-storage

Hi am trying to download `.zip` file from `firebase` storage using code

```
FirebaseStorage httpsReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference reference = httpsReference.getReferenceFromUrl(Constants.FIREBASE_ST_URL);
StorageReference referenceNew = reference.child("ImageSets").child(post.get("SetName") + ".zip");
Log.d("log_tag", "ZIP URL referenceNew : " + referenceNew.toString()); 
//**this is log result** gs://memory-matcch.appspot.com/ImageSets/set_2.zip

referenceNew.getFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Log.d("log_tag", "ZIP FILE onSuccess : " + Uri.fromFile(file) + "\nPath : " + file.getPath() + "\nAbsolute : " + file.getAbsolutePath());

    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
```

**and this is fire base rule**
[image]

**this is firebase storage**
[image]

and I am getting this error

```
Exception occurred during file download
java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:932)
at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I want to do this without login in fire base as I ant that user can download zip without login also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.getFile(file)` seems to be your problem--what is `file`? This download the zip to your local filesystem, and it appears, as the exception states, "No such file or directory".

Try `getBytes()` or `getStream()` to download in memory, or pick a valid file to write to.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to provide two-arguments first File or second Name in which you want to give that file
Like:

```
storageRefrence.getFile(fileDirectory, fileName).addOnCompleteListener(new ...);
```